# Will a ban never be lifted permanently?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am a new user in MathSE, and I had posted 2 questions, one of which I did not explain my working, and another which was a duplicate (my poor $\LaTeX$ is to blame for me not getting duplicates).

I got a redemption question after 7 days: and I used it, and posted one - which has got 2k views, a 'Popular Question' badge, and a score of 7 as of now, which according to my experiences with ChemSE or PhySE, is quite great.

Now my ban has been reinstated once more. I am not able to post questions, and again I am doubtful whether the other redemption question that I might post after 7 days will actually redeem me from my ban.

[Something's not right about my understanding about identity matrices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830236/somethings-not-right-about-my-understanding-about-identity-matrices) - this is my redemption post.

I don't see any scope for my other questions being revived and updated since I've already got them or they are duplicates in MathSE.

My situation is on a tightrope walk, and I surely don't see a bright future in MathSE for me.

Can anyone please let me know if:

1. I will be getting only 1 question per week to ask?
2. Is there any redemption from this vicious cycle?

P.S., apologies to Xander Henderson for the previous rants - it was quite frustrating for me that day when I was first banned, being quite unfamiliar about the SE culture.